# DOM-Manipulating extension for grade calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm currently working on a Chrome Extension that uses jQuery to traverse and manipulate the DOM in order to read and write hypothetical grade calculations to a gradebook page. I already have a [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/TheOdd/what-if-grades) for it with a demo gif if you're interested in seeing the visuals of it.

I'd like to preface this post by saying that **the current code is working perfectly and functioning as intended**, but my concern pertains to the readability and practices of how it currently works. I'm currently in the process of refactoring a lot of the code in order to accomplish a couple of key things:

- Have a minimal number of static variables with "magic number" type values in them. †
- Make code more readable for both myself and possible contributors or anyone referencing the code. This includes naming functions logically and specifically, grouping certain areas of code, etc.
- Break apart the code into smaller sections that make sense based on the action that they perform. This makes the code easier to read, follow, and understand.
- Get the code to be as *[self-documenting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209015/what-is-self-documenting-code-and-can-it-replace-well-documented-code)* as possible (which will help de-clutter a lot of the comments littered throughout the code).
- Separate helper functions (i.e. functions that perform a lot of the actual actions on the page) and the contexts and functions in which they are called in (i.e. click handlers)

**†**: *I understand that, due to the nature of this project, there will be quite a few of these type of variables that will have to stay, but I'd like to have as few as possible.*

I'm also looking for any advice on where the line is for making this code readable, but keeping it efficient and practical (best practices)

My **current code** is as follows:

```
// Check if user is on gradebook page as opposed to dashboard
if (window.location.href !== 'https://apps.houstonisd.org/ParentStudentConnect/GradeSpeed.aspx') {
  $(document).ready(function() {

    // Create button element to be placed next to each grade
    var button = $('<span/>', {
      text: ' ✍',
      class: 'edit-grade-button',
      style: 'cursor: pointer;'
    });

    var tables = $('table.DataTable').slice(1).children(); // Get all data tables (aka grade sections)
    var addGrade = $('<tr class="DataRow add-grade-row"><td class="AssignmentName"><button class="script-add-grade-button">Add new grade</button></td><td class="DateAssigned">&nbsp;</td><td class="DateDue">&nbsp;</td><td class="script-placeholder">&nbsp;</td><td class="AssignmentNote">&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>'); // Create row elements for buttons
    var addGradeAlt = $('<tr class="DataRowAlt add-grade-row"><td class="AssignmentName"><button class="script-add-grade-button">Add new grade</button></td><td class="DateAssigned">&nbsp;</td><td class="DateDue">&nbsp;</td><td class="script-placeholder">&nbsp;</td><td class="AssignmentNote">&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>'); // Create row elements for buttons
    tables.each(function addButton() { // Add the 'add new grade' button to each section at the bottom
      var targetRow = $(this).children().last().prev(); // Get last row from current table
      if (targetRow.attr('class') === 'DataRow') { // Check if either alt style or regular style
        targetRow.addClass('script-add-grade-alt'); // Based on condition, add appropriate style
      } else {
        targetRow.addClass('script-add-grade'); // Based on condition, add appropriate style
      }
    });
    $('.script-add-grade-alt').after(addGradeAlt).removeClass('script-add-grade-alt'); // For whatever reason, trying to add the addGrade elements
    $('.script-add-grade').after(addGrade).removeClass('script-add-grade'); // after the targetrow while in the loop did not work, but this did.

    $('.script-add-grade-button').click(function clickHandler(e) {
      e.preventDefault(); // Prevent default action (redirection)
      var myButton = button.clone(); // Normally, you can only assign an element once. That can be to multiple targets, but I can't do it just once in this case,
                                     // so I make a copy of the element after each click in order to make a unique element for that click to be assigned
      var currentRow = $(this).parent().parent(); // Get two parents above in order to get actual row element
      var assignmentName = prompt('Assignment name.'); // Prompt user for assignment name and store it in a variable
      var row = $('<tr class="DataRow"><td class="AssignmentName">' + assignmentName + '</td><td class="DateAssigned">N/A</td><td class="DateDue">N/A</td><td class="AssignmentGrade script-grade">' + 0 + '</td><td class="AssignmentNote"></td></tr>'); // Create element to be placed as new grade row
      var rowAlt = $('<tr class="DataRowAlt"><td class="AssignmentName">' + assignmentName + '</td><td class="DateAssigned">N/A</td><td class="DateDue">N/A</td><td class="AssignmentGrade script-grade">' + 0 + '</td><td class="AssignmentNote"></td></tr>'); // Create element to be placed as new grade row
      if (currentRow.attr('class').match(/(DataRow\b|DataRowAlt\b)/)[0] === 'DataRow') { // Match regex pattern for either DataRow or DataRowAlt
        currentRow.removeClass('DataRow').addClass('DataRowAlt').before(row).prev().children('.script-grade').after(myButton); // Invert data row CSS and add button next to new grade
      } else {
        currentRow.removeClass('DataRowAlt').addClass('DataRow').before(rowAlt).prev().children('.script-grade').after(myButton); // Invert data row CSS and add button next to new grade
      }
      currentRow.prev().children('.script-grade').next().trigger('click'); // Initiate the click event handler to trigger chain of events to handle new grades
    });

    // 'AssignmentGrade' is a class attached to all grade elements on the page, including the headers titled 'Grade'
    $('.AssignmentGrade').filter(function removeHeaders(index, elem) {
      return $(this).text() !== 'Grade'; // Exclude headers from jQuery selection result
    }).addClass('script-grade'); // Assign all remaining elements a class so it could be easily referenced later

    // Pretty much some magic numbers here, but they should stay consistent with the way that the gradebook is layed out.
    // 'tbody' elements are the elements surrounding each section of grades (i.e. classwork, homework, projects, etc.), but also
    // include the overall grades at the top, as well as the 'Current Average' section for the currently selected grades.
    $('tbody')
    .slice(2) // The first two 'tbody' elements are the overall grades and current average section, which we don't want.

    .children('tr:not([class])') // The children of those remaining 'tbody' elements all have classes except for the averages listed at the bottom,
                                 // so get the elements that don't have a class.

    .children() // The children of those elements are just 4 elements. 2 of them are strange blank characters (not spaces, which is weird), 1 of them
                // is the title of 'Average', and the last is the actual average.
    .filter(function filterOnlyAvg(index, elem) {
      return $(this).text() !== " " && $(this).text() !== "Average"; // Filter out to only get the actual averages
    }).addClass('script-avg'); // Assign all remaining elements a class so it could be easily referenced later

    $('.script-grade').after(button); // Add the button next to every grade that we tagged earlier
    $('.edit-grade-button').next().next().remove() // Remove extra indentation, as button replaced it

    $(document).on('avg-change', '.script-avg', function handleAvgChange() { // Listen for when the averages change
      var calcArr = []; // Create empty array that will be populated later w/ [weight, avg] pairs
      var weightArr = $('.CategoryName').contents(); // Base selection of weights
      var avgArr = $('.script-avg').contents(); // Base selection of averages

      weightArr = Array.from(weightArr); // The selection is technically an element group or something. Pretty much not an array.

      // If there is only one weight, then it's automatically 100%, so check.

      if (weightArr.length > 1) {
        weightArr = weightArr.map(function parseWeight(weightStr) {
          var txt = $(weightStr).text(); // Since each element in the array is an HTML element, we parse it with the jQuery wrapper
          return parseInt(txt.slice(txt.length - 3, txt.length - 1)); // We then slice the string to be only the percent number at the end and parse it as an integer.
        });
      } else {
        weightArr = [100]; // Set to 100% if only one section
      }

      avgArr = Array.from(avgArr); // Repeat same process as above w/ averages
      avgArr = avgArr.map(function parseAvg(avgStr) {
        var txt = $(avgStr).text();
        return parseFloat(txt); // Just parse each element's text as a float, not an int
      });

      var totalWeight = 0; // Make variable to hold the total present weight in order to get ratio of 100 later

      for (var i = 0; i < weightArr.length; i++) {
        if (!isNaN(avgArr[i])) { // Filter out only averages that actually exists. Get rid of '--' or blank averages.
          calcArr.push([weightArr[i], avgArr[i]]); // Push the result to the calcArr as a pair of both the weight and average.
          totalWeight += weightArr[i]; // Add weight to total.
        }
      }

      var weightedAvg = 0; // Create variable for the new overall class average based on changed numbers
      var ratio = 100 / totalWeight; // Calculate ratio - 100% over the total weight present
      calcArr.forEach(function sumWeightedAvg(pair) {
        weightedAvg += (pair[0] * (ratio/100)) * pair[1]; // Calculate the weighted result for each average and add them to the total.
      });

      $('.CurrentAverage').text('Current Average: ' + weightedAvg.toFixed(2)); // Finally, set the 'Current Average' text to the newly-calculated average
    });

    $(document).on('grade-change', '.script-grade', function handleGradeChange() { // Listen for when grades change
      var avg = $(this).closest('tbody').find('.script-avg'); // Find closest average
      var gradeArr = $(this).closest('tbody').children().children('.script-grade').contents(); // Get array of all grades in current section

      gradeArr = Array.from(gradeArr); // Same process as with the weightArr above
      gradeArr = gradeArr.map(function parseGrades(gradeStr) {
        return parseInt($(gradeStr).text()); // Parse the text into a float
      });

      var newAvg = 0; // Make variable to store newly-calculated average
      gradeArr.forEach(function sumGrades(grade) {
        newAvg += grade; // Add all grades together from array
      });
      newAvg /= gradeArr.length; // Divide total by number of grades to get average
      avg.text(newAvg.toFixed(2)); // Set average text to the new average
      avg.trigger('avg-change'); // Trigger the average change event
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.edit-grade-button', function handleBtnClick() { // Listen for when the edit buttons are clicked
      var grade = $(this).prev(); // Get the grade associated with the clicked button
      var newGrade = Number(prompt('New value')); // Prompt user for new value
      while (isNaN(newGrade)) { // Re-Prompt until user enters valid number
        newGrade = Number(prompt('New value'));
      }
      grade.text(newGrade); // Set grade's text to new value
      grade.trigger('grade-change'); // Trigger the grade change event
    });
  });
} else { // If user is on page where you select 'grades', run this

  // The reason why we can't operate on the regular page is because the grade elements and everything that we need to work on
  // is inside an iFrame, which we can't access due to security restrictions. Luckily, the iFrame source is just a link to another page,
  // so just redirect them to that actual page and everything will be loaded as normal without being wrapped in an iFrame container.

  $(document).ready(function changeLink() {
    $('#ctl00_ln_close').text("Open 'what if' grade viewer"); // Set the text of the 'Close GradeBook' link (which is never used) to open grades page in standalone tab
    $('#ctl00_ln_close').attr('href', 'https://parent.gradebook.houstonisd.org/pc/ParentStudentGrades.aspx'); // Set to proper link
  });
}
```

I've done my best to document and explain the code, but it's gotten to the point where the comments almost make it harder to read and clutter the code significantly. This is the main reason why I want the code to be primarily self-documenting.

My **refactored code** so far is as follows:

```
var helpers = {
  newButtonElem: function newButton() {
    return $('<span/>', {
      text: ' ✍',
      class: 'edit-grade-button',
      style: 'cursor: pointer;'
    });
  },
  newAddGradeElem: function newAddGradeElem(style) {
    var rowStyle = null;
    if (style === 'alt') {
      rowStyle = 'DataRowAlt';
    } else if (style === 'normal') {
      rowStyle = 'DataRow';
    } else {
      throw 'Please specify a valid style for the new addGradeElem!';
    }
    return $('<tr/>', {'class': rowStyle + ' add-grade-row'}).append(
      $('<td/>', {'class': 'AssignmentName'}).append(
        $('<button/>', {'class': 'script-add-grade-button',
                        'text': 'Add new grade'});
        $('<td/>', {'class': 'DateAssigned',
                    'text': '&nbsp;'});
        $('<td/>', {'class': 'DateDue'},
                    'text': '&nbsp;');
        $('<td/>', {'class': 'script-placeholder',
                    'text': '&nbsp;'});
        $('<td/>', {'class': 'AssignmentNote',
                    'text': '&nbsp;'});
        $('<td/>', {'text': '&nbsp;'});
      );
    );
  },
  flipRowStyle: function flipRowStyle(currentRow, assignmentName) {
    var row = null; // Add helper function
    var rowAlt = null; // Add helper function
    var isDataRow = currentRow.attr('class').match(/(DataRow\b|DataRowAlt\b)/)[0] === 'DataRow';
    var rowToAdd = isDataRow ? row : rowAlt;
    var newButton = helpers.newButtonElem();
    var classToRemove = isDataRow ? 'DataRow' : 'DataRowAlt';
    var classToAdd = isDataRow ? 'DataRowAlt': 'DataRow';
    currentRow.removeClass(classToRemove).addClass(classToAdd).before(rowToAdd).prev().children('.script-grade').after(newButton);
  }
}

function insertAddNewGradeButtons() {
  var tables = $('table.DataTable').slice(1).children();
  tables.each(function addButton() {
    var addGrade = helpers.newAddGradeElem('normal');
    var addGradeAlt = helpers.newAddGradeElem('alt');
    var targetRow = $(this).children().last().prev();
    if (targetRow.attr('class') === 'DataRow') {
      targetRow.after(addGradeAlt);
    } else {
      targetRow.after(addGrade);
    }
  });
}

function addGradeButtonClickHandler() {
  $('.script-add-grade-button').click(function clickHandler(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var currentRow = $(this).parent().parent();
    var assignmentName = prompt('Assignment name.');
    helpers.flipRowStyle(currentRow, assignmentName);
    currentRow.prev().children('.script-grade').next().trigger('click');
  });
}
```

Obviously, this code isn't complete and is missing a lot of functionality from the original, but I wanted to get some outside eyes and opinions on where I'm going with the refactored code before continuing to write it. If you need any additional information, I'd be happy to provide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breaking up the lengthy code above into smaller methods with a helpful name is a good thing. What you are essentially achieving is for each of those small methods to have a [single responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

You could go a step further and remove hard-coded side-effects from some of these methods. This can be achieved by pulling the `$` selectors (which is essentially a global function acting on another global, the DOM) up the call chain. E.g.:

```
function addGradeButtonClickHandler(button) {
  button.click(function clickHandler(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var currentRow = $(this).parent().parent();
    var assignmentName = prompt('Assignment name.');
    helpers.flipRowStyle(currentRow, assignmentName);
    currentRow.prev().children('.script-grade').next().trigger('click');
  });
}
```

This means the function now only acts on objects it is given. It is somehow decoupled from the DOM which could make the function more reusable. It could now be called twice with different arguments (e.g. in an automated test).

```
addGradeButtonClickHandler($('.script-add-grade-button'))
```

Comment: Thanks for the great info. I'm going to hold off on marking it as the correct answer until after I let the question sit for a day just to allow for other answers, but this is looking promising!